# Modifying Rails logging level per request on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

There is so little information about managing log levels out there, that I decided to ask this question to get your opinion on this.

The motivation behind this question is to find out the optimal way of setting the log levels in production without restarting the app server.

First thing that I can think about is putting a method in an `application_controller` which will check for certain url parameter existence i.e `log_level=debug` and turn that logging level if it exists for the life of the request.

This has one drawback, which is that your user or you have to modify the url to turn on the logging. Another one might be that any underlying calls you make i.e via javascript call to you api also needs to be aware of this change and pass this `log_level` url param.

Another thing I can think is putting a file to your Rails root directory called `debug_log_level` or something similar, then on each request start check if that file exists. When it does, checking is the filename actually containing the valid logging level, and when it does turning that logging level on.

Drawback of this one is that you might have several instances on different boxes, so you would need to go on each box to make this change.

Another one could be to make a call to a database and same the same flow like for file.

Alternatively you could set an environment variable for log level, and use that to set the log level, but that would require the app server restart.

How are you managing this in your production environment? There has to be a smarter way to do this by now, is there?

Comment: Why not restarting the app server is so important? Instead of a database or environment variable that needs to set in each box, you could also use Redis or any other key/value storage accessible from all apps.

Comment: Toggling settings like this could be trouble, these might leak out of the context of an individual request and affect everything. You might want to create another environment that's more verbose and use that for testing.

Comment: @tadman I m ok with debugging staying on as long as the file is there or whatever. Any potential downsides other than leaking to multiple requests?

Comment: @Leito adding redis to our stack for this purpose alone I feel like it's not worth the benefit. I love redis btw, and admire it's capabilities other than just being a key/value datastore. But I like the way you're thinking, there is one thing however problematic with this is that I can't directly modify redis key/values without launching a redis console, or having some kind of process that sets/resets the logging value to redis.

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow Checking for a file will have a minor drag on performance, but if that's acceptable you should be fine.

Comment: @tadman I realize that, any better options? I m looking into what I can do now. thanks

Comment: It's an unusual thing to have to do. My approach is to deploy a special server running the same code, same database, but with different logging levels with a name like `debug.mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com`.

Comment: @tadman you mean like a staging environment of a sort, yes we have that. Basically it mirrors a production environment. When thinking about this that seems like a most logical approach when the staging environment exists. In the case of staging its not that important if I have to restart the app server, so I ll probably be taking the environment variable approach. Just weird that we don't have this issue solved in a more elegant way in 2016. I mean not all projects have staging environment.

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow It's 2016 so setting up a staging environment should be super easy. With tools like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) and [Docker](https://www.docker.com), plus on-demand pay-by-the-hour servers, it's really not hard to automate.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels), you can set the log level in an environment initializer (e.g. in `config/environments/production.rb`) with the following:

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

where instead of `:warn` you specify your desired log level.

> The available log levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, and :unknown, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5 respectively.

If you need to specify the log level at run time, you can use

```
Rails.logger.level = 0
```